# Showing clear button in a non-editable UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am showing a UITextField to the user and the text inside this text field is updated by a different controller.

User cannot type inside this UITextField. I ensured this by doing the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return NO;
}
```

But I want to show the clear icon in the text field, so that the user can clear the value in textfield. I do that by doing the following:

```
_inputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

But the clear button does not show up when there is a text inside it :(

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The clearButton only show up when there is some text in the textField

Comment: I am adding text to the textfield programatically and it is not showing up

Comment: Per the docs: "The overlay view is displayed only while text is being edited in the text field." So if you are not in editing mode, it won't show up. Maybe try `_inputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;`

Comment: Just put a small button on it.

Comment: Can you try making the text field as first responder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
customTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

customTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true;

func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom button and add it to textfield's rightView

```
UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[clearButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[clearButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)];
// If you need action
[clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearTextField) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


 _inputField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
 _inputField.rightView = clearButton;
 _inputField.rightView.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `UITextFieldDelegate` and set delegate to your textField

```
_inputField.delegate = self;
```